# Python regex: get all the non digits, in groups, followed or not by a space

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex:

```
(?P<value>[0-9]+)(\s*)(?P<unit>[^\d+? ])
```

and the string:

```
432 gfd-gfd gfg fd 4445 kk/ t%
```

For the `base` is only taking the first letter: `g, k.`
What I want is to extract:

```
gfd-gfd, gfg, fd, kk/, t%
```

Comment: You want to get 4 matches? `gfd-gfd`, `gfg`, `fd` and `kk/ t%`? What is the logic for the last match `kk/ t%`?

Comment: yes, more matches, I updated, kk/ and t% are separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will match any group of characters that does not contain a space or a digit:

```
[^\d\s]+

[^   // don't match any characters in this group
  \d // any digit
  \s // any whitespace
]+   // match one or more characters that meet these criteria
```

This matches all of the strings you wanted in your test case.

Comment: doesn't match  t%

Comment: Be sure to use the global flag. You can see this regex here: https://regex101.com/r/bVanNV/1 - It is using the python flavor, so if it is not working, let me know what result you are seeing. It matches `t%` on my test, and on that website. Beyond that, I'll need more information to know what's going wrong